# IllegalAccessError after updating Android Studio

Tags: android

After updating to the latest Google Services and Firebase library versions my previously stable application (99.6% crash free users) has become unstable with 25% of users beginning to experience crashes.

I changed no code in my application. The only changes I made were to the Grade files to update to the latest versions. I am getting an error that I can find no information about online anywhere:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService
dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative (DexFile.java)
dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass (DexFile.java:226)
dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName (DexFile.java:219)
dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass (DexPathList.java:338)
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:2859)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1427)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5421)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Or one of a variety of similar exceptions like this:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzge implemented by class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver' appears in /data/app/com.mycompanyname/base.apk)
java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass (VMClassLoader.java)
java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass (ClassLoader.java:738)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:363)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3299)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17 ()
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1771)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6753)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:482)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

My top level gradle file has these libraries in it:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the (redacted) model gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    flavorDimensions "default"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /*implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'*/
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I had issues with Proguard after the upgrade, so maybe it is related to that. My Proguard rules:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**
-keepnames class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
```

Update:

I thought maybe I had reached the point that I needed to multidex. But analysing the APK shows "This dex file defines 5112 classes with 30311 methods, and references 36641 methods."

Interestingly, contrasting this new bad APK with the old working one, the new one has a lot of libraries additional to it, things like play-services-basement, play-services-gass, etc.

Comment: The same happened to me, doesn't matter if multidex is enabled or not. But the thing is, that it crashes only at the first time after install from Google Play, second and next open is problem-less. Also when the same .apk is installed directly, no error occurs.

Comment: @theMatus My Firebase reports show that some of my users were hitting the same crash multiple times, so for me it can't be only the first time it's opened. I rolled back to the old versions of everything for now and am not getting the crashes anymore. If I update the apps I'll likely be removing Google Play Services libraries to avoid this mess again.

Comment: Actually around 5% got this more times, but I'm still not sure why, hopefully developers will fix this soon, so I can update it again.

Answer (score 0):

Alright after some little research, only thing that helped me was to update google play services to 4.0.0+....